# Example of Buffer Overflow?

Tags: c, memory, buffer, endianness, buffer-overflow

I was reading about buffer overflow in my book and saw:

[image: Stack]

Is the order of how the string was loaded into memory correct? In little endian I read that we load the bits at lower index in lower addresses but this example shows the opposite.

Now Given this code:

[image: Example Code]

How can I set auth_flag to 1? The string which has an ascii value of 1 isn't printable so this seems as impossible to exploit, am I right?

Comment: Any non-zero value is interpreted as `true`, so you don't actually need to set `auth_flag` to 1. Any non-zero value will work. The bigger problem is that `auth_flag` could be stored as a register value, or could be in memory before the buffer, so overrunning the buffer doesn't necessarily affect `auth_flag`.

Comment: endianess does not apply to strings

Comment: Did you try compiling with optimization off and entering a 17-char password such as "slithy toves mome"?  Use a debugger to see the addresses and values.

Comment: @user3386109 what if I want exactly 1?

Comment: It's questionable whether you can get the ASCII character 0x01 past the terminal, through the shell, and into `argv`.

Comment: @4386427 why? they are loaded in memory...

Comment: [What is CPU endianness?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code example 1:**

> In little endian I read that we load the bits at lower index in lower addresses but this example shows the opposite.

When using simple C-style character strings endianess doesn't apply. Endianess is relevant for multi-byte values but not for char values.

**Code example 2:**

> The string which has an ascii value of 1 isn't printable so this seems as impossible to exploit, am I right?

No, you have a basic misunderstanding here. You don't need to get the numeric value 1 into `auth_flag`. You only need a **non-zero** value.

Remember that

```
if (check_authentication(argv[1])) {
```

is really

```
if (check_authentication(argv[1]) != 0) {
                                  ^^^^
```

so the if-condition will be true for any non-zero return value.

To break the authentication check the idea is that the compiler place `auth_flag` somewhere in memory **after** `password_buffer`. In that case you can give the program a start argument longer than 16 characters so that the extra characters overflows the buffer and end at the location of `auth_flag`.

Here is a rewrite of your code. The principle is the same. I just used shorther names and removed some (unnecessary) code to make the example simple. Also I print the location of the variables.

```
int ca(char* pw)
{
    int af = 0;
    char pw_b[16];
    printf("af   location: %p\n", (void*)&af);
    printf("pw_b location: %p\n", (void*)pw_b);

    strcpy(pw_b, pw);
    return af;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
      printf("wrong usage\n");
      return 0;
  }
  if (ca(argv[1]))
  {
      printf("Did it...\n");
  }
  else
  {
      printf("Failed to break in\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -O0` I get this output when starting like `./prog abc`

```
af   location: 0x7ffd579e13cc
pw_b location: 0x7ffd579e13b0
Failed to break in
```

From this I can see that `af` is located 0x1c bytes (or 28 decimal) **after** `pw_b`. So if I give the program an argument being longer than 28 characters, it may overwrite `af` (if it doesn't crash for other reasons....).

So I tried `./prog 1234567890123456789012345678b` (notice 29 characters in the string) and I got:

```
af   location: 0x7ffc63312f8c
pw_b location: 0x7ffc63312f70
Did it...
```

So I was successful... I did hack the authentication check code.

But notice... On another system, with another compiler, with other compiler option, etc. things may be different. So you can't be sure to reproduce this on your system. Maybe you'll need different input, maybe it won't even be possible on your system. Start by checking where the variables are located and then calculate the input required.

Comment: Q1) Regarding the very first part of your answer (Part 1), chars are bytes too. Still I didn't get that

Comment: Q2) Regarding 2, what if I really wanted `auth_flag` to hold the value 1 How can I do that or it's impossible? Please relate to all questions, Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Daniel Re Q2: All the normal characters have decimal values as defined in the ascii table used. So you can't use a normal character. However, it may be possible to use some escape sequence at the command line to enter the decimal value 1. Typically starting a `\` (e.g. `\01`) but it may depend on your shell. So I can't answer.

Comment: @Daniel Re Q1: A character string is saved in memory with the first character at lowest address. Always... so endianess isn't relevant for character strings.

Comment: @Daniel "I know but character is still a decimal..." True but there is no bytes to swap so there is no endianess for chars